# How do I change the color of my filter text in dash table?

Tags: datatable, datatables, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have this table-

```
html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id = 'datatable-interactivity',
        data = df.to_dict('records'),
        editable = False,
        style_filter = {
            'backgroundColor': '#252e3f',
            'color': 'white'
        },
        style_header = {
            'backgroundColor': '#252e3f',
            'color': 'white'
        },
        style_data = {
            'backgroundColor': '#252e3f',
            'color': 'white'
        },
        style_cell = {
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
            'maxWidth': 0
        }
    )])  
], style = {'background-color': '#1f2630'})
```

The filter text shows up as a dark gray even though I set the color to white. This includes both the text that I add into the filter cells and the default placeholders.

Is there a different argument I should include to change the color?

Comment: There is an error in the provided code, I think in the parenthesis. Add the full code of `app.layout`

Comment: Does this link help https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-datatable-style-filter-doesnt-seem-to-work/15691/5 ?